# in der Jahrhunderte währenden Entflechtung

Tags: grammar-identification

> in der Jahrhunderte währenden Entflechtung

I am not able to connect the noun *Jahrhunderte* and *Entflechtung* meaningfully.
Could you explain the above phrase grammatically?

Here is the full quote:

> Das „Reichsgesetz über die Beurkundung des Personenstands und die Eheschließung“ vom 6. Februar 1875 war ein Eckstein bürgerlicher Gesetzgebung in Deutschland – ein Höhepunkt **in der Jahrhunderte währenden Entflechtung** von Staat und Kirche.

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you about that phrase?

Comment: I am not able to connect the noun Jahrhunderte and Entflechtung meaningfully

Comment: "Die Entflechtung währte Jahrhunderte" == "Disentanglement took ages". Whether you consider this an accusative object or a temporal qualifier doesn't really matter very much; the second noun is a complement of the verb and that's that.

Comment: It's quite common in German like "Der Geld zahlende Konzertbesucher".

Answer (score 6):

in der (Jahrhunderte währenden) Entflechtung - (...) serves as an adjective. It uses the Partizip I "währenden" -> (an)dauernden. So all-in-all it's: in der Entflechtung, die Jahrhunderte währte (= (an)dauerte).

Comment: If it were used a proper adjective, we should have a single word "jahrundertwährenden". It does have an adjectival function, but it's not encoded as an adjective in terms of spelling.

Answer (score 1):

> ... Höhepunkt in der Jahrhunderte währenden Entflechtung von Staat und Kirche.

means

... Höhepunkt in der ... Entflechtung von Staat und Kirche. Diese Entflechtung währte (dauerte) Jahrhunderte.

So *Jahrhunderte während* is an Attribute of *Entflechtung*. Since *die Entflechtung* is feminine, it's *Jahrhunderte während**e** Entflechtung*. And since *in* is asking for dative, it's

> In der Jahrhunderte während**en** Entflechtung (war das Gesetz ein Höhepunkt).